# Check mandatory fields in Vaadin and Java

Tags: java, validation, vaadin

I have attached a listener to lots of input elements, which when executed runs a `checkButton();`-method, which checks whether any fields are empty and then displays buttons according to th result. My problem is that sometimes the request takes quite long or hangs. So I have this hypothesis that it is the multiple calls to the `checkButton();`-method which are the cause.

How could I merge several calls to the `checkButton();`-method into one? Is there a recommended way to do this?

```
ValueChangeListener<String> mandatoryChangeListener = new ValueChangeListener<String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        log.debug("mandatoryChangeListener.addValueChangeListener");
        checkButtonState();
    }
};

protected void registerMandatoryInputs() {  

    //registerMandatoryInput(kpiCategories.cbExtraInfo, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(tKpiDescription, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(tKpiName, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(tFrequency, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(cbFrequencyUnit, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(cbBusinessProcess, mandatoryChangeListener);
    registerMandatoryInput(cbBusinessEvent, mandatoryChangeListener);

    kpiThresholds.registerMandatoryInputs(mandatoryChangeListener);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void registerMandatoryInput(Component c, ValueChangeListener<String> listener) {
    if(c instanceof TextField) {
        ((TextField) c).addValueChangeListener(listener);
    } else if(c instanceof ComboBox) {
        ((ComboBox<String>) c).addValueChangeListener(listener);
    } else if(c instanceof TextArea) {
        ((TextArea) c).addValueChangeListener(listener);
    } else {
        log.info("Component could not be registered as mandatory: " + c.getClass().toString());
    }
}
private boolean inCheckButtonState = false;
protected void checkButtonState() {
    log.debug("checkButtonState ..");
    if(!inCheckButtonState) {
        inCheckButtonState = true;

        boolean okEdit = checkMandatoryFields();
        boolean okThresholds = kpiThresholds.validateMandatoryFields() && !mustHaveClickedOnThresholdsButton;
        if( okEdit && okThresholds) {
            log.debug("checkButtonState enable ..");
            enableButton(bSaveKpi);
            enableButton(bUpdateKpi);

            enableButton(bSaveKpiThresholds);
            enableButton(bUpdateKpiThresholds);

            enableButton(bEnable);
            enableButton(bDisable);
        } else {
            log.debug("checkButtonState disable ..");
            disableButton(bSaveKpi);
            disableButton(bUpdateKpi);

            disableButton(bSaveKpiThresholds);
            disableButton(bUpdateKpiThresholds);

            disableButton(bEnable);
            disableButton(bDisable);
        }

        if(okEdit) {
            log.debug("checkButtonState enable Navigation..");
            enableButton(bToThresholds);
        } else {
            log.debug("checkButtonState disable Navigation..");
            disableButton(bToThresholds);
        }

        if(okThresholds) {
            log.debug("checkButtonState enable Navigation back..");
            enableButton(bBackToEdit);
            bToThresholds.setComponentError(null);
        } else {
            log.debug("checkButtonState disable Navigation back..");
            disableButton(bBackToEdit);
            if(mustHaveClickedOnThresholdsButton) {
                String clickMessage = messageByLocaleService.getMessage("message.checkthresholds");
                bToThresholds.setComponentError(new UserError(clickMessage));
            } else {
                bToThresholds.setComponentError(null);
            }
        }
    }
    inCheckButtonState = false;
}

protected static void disableButton(Button b) {
    b.addStyleName("test-data");
    b.setEnabled(false);
}

protected static void enableButton(Button b) {
    b.removeStyleName("test-data");
    b.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "hypothesis"? You are logging each execution of ``checkButtonState``, so you know how frequently it is called, don't you? Furthermore, you always remove/add styles and en/disable the buttons with no regard to the state they are in. There is no need to disable a button when it is already in state _disabled_.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is. Vaadin is awesome as to simplicity of design, but it is not (and never was) very efficient. The number of BE calls is overwhelming (just check network debug tools in chrome to see how right I am) What you can do is write your own implementation of Container / Layout (sorry if I'm not being precise, it's been a while since I touched Vaadin) with the validation logic on client side, and attach a single listener to it, but not having to do that is kinda the reason to use Vaadin in the first place ;)

On a side note, why don't you use built-in `required` property? This will handle much of the validation for you. Especially if you bind all your components to a `FieldGroup`, you will then be able to perform the validation with a single `fieldGroup.validate()` call. If additional validators are required, you can just use `Component#addValidator()`

edit:
btw, is it just a hunch You have, or have you actually tried debugging to see what happens?

edit2:
Oh I just noticed, that you check ALL your fields after each single field edit - why would you do that? Instead of adding `ValueChangeListener`s try using `Validator`s, that's what they're for! If you want them to work in real time you can just use `Component#setImmediate`

Comment: Your reply seems to be based on Vaadin 7 (e.g. `FieldGroup` and `setImmediate`), but the question seems to be based on Vaadin 8 (since  `ValueChangeListener` has a generic type).

Comment: @LeifÅstrand hah, indeed, I haven't used Vaadin 8, and somehow missed those diamonds there ;)